# org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl missing in nutch 1.9 on hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I have installed fully distributed Hadoop 1.2.1. I was trying to integrated nutch with steps below:

1. Download apache-nutch-1.9-src.zip
2. Add value http.agent.name into nutch-site.xml
3. Copy `hadoop-env.sh`, `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`, `mapred-site.xml`,
   `masters`, `slaves` into $NUTCH_HOME/conf
4. compile using `ant runtime`
5. create `urls/seed.txt` and put on hadoop dfs
6. edit $NUTCH_HOME/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt

Test crawl using command:

`bin/hadoop -jar nutch-1.9.job org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl urls -dir urls -depth 1 -topN 5`

and get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl**
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)

I tried extract nutch-1.9.job and I didn't find out class Crawl in org/apache/nutch/crawl.

Do I need to config something?

Answer (score 1):

Crawl.java removed at 1.8 version. You can use crawl shell script for all crawling.

Deprecated class o.a.n.crawl.Crawler is still in code base https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1621